# Encoding and Decoding Class Objects between Python and JSON

Tags: python, json, inheritance, decode, encode

I'm encoding and decoding inherited classes between Python 2.7 and a JSON file. This *works*, but I'm concerned that as I add types, I will need to keep expanding the encoder and decoder to check every type. Is there a more automatic way to convert the class to JSON and back again? It doesn't necessarily need to be an enum.

More specifically, I'm trying to encode and decode a list of equipment objects which all inherit from the Equipment class. Right now, I'm encoding by looking at the isinstance variable, and if it matches one of the subclasses (Transformer, GeneralEquipment, or Motor), I'm adding an extra enum key to the JSON for the equipment type. Then when I decode, the same check happens in reverse. But this means expanding that check for every sub-class I create, and there may be 10-20 equipment types when I'm done.

```
import json
import math
from enum import Enum

class EquipType(str, Enum):
    GeneralEquipment = 'GENERAL_EQUIPMENT'
    Transformer = 'TRANSFORMER'
    Motor = 'MOTOR'

class Equipment:

    VA = None

    def __init__(self, tag='', volts=0, phases=1, fla=0):
        self.tag = tag
        self.volts = volts
        self.phases = phases
        self.fla = fla

    def volt_amps(self):
        if self.phases == 3:
            self.VA = self.volts*self.fla*math.sqrt(3)
        else:
            self.VA = self.volts*self.fla

    def wire_size(self):
        print "calculated as if this were equipment."

class GeneralEquipment(Equipment):
    def wire_size(self):
        print "calculated as if this were general equipment."

class Transformer(Equipment):
    def wire_size(self):
        print "calculated as if this were a transformer."

class Motor(Equipment):
    def wire_size(self):
        print "calculated as if this were a motor."

class EquipmentEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, z):
        if isinstance(z, GeneralEquipment):
            return {"equiptype" : EquipType.GeneralEquipment, "tag" : z.tag, "volts" : z.volts, "phases" : z.phases, "fla" : z.fla}
        elif isinstance(z, Transformer):
            return {"equiptype" : EquipType.Transformer, "tag" : z.tag, "volts" : z.volts, "phases" : z.phases, "fla" : z.fla}
        elif isinstance(z, Motor):
            return {"equiptype" : EquipType.Motor, "tag" : z.tag, "volts" : z.volts, "phases" : z.phases, "fla" : z.fla}
        else:
            return super().default(z)

def EquipmentDecoder(dct):
    if dct['equiptype'] == EquipType.GeneralEquipment:
        return Equipment(dct['tag'],dct['volts'],dct['phases'],dct['fla'])
    elif dct['equiptype'] == EquipType.Transformer:
        return Transformer(dct['tag'],dct['volts'],dct['phases'],dct['fla'])
    elif dct['equiptype'] == EquipType.Motor:
        return Motor(dct['tag'],dct['volts'],dct['phases'],dct['fla'])

MyEquipList = [GeneralEquipment('EF-1 (Bathroom fan)',120,1,5),Transformer('XMFR-2',208,3,5),Motor('EF-23',480,3,24)]

print(MyEquipList)
print(MyEquipList[0].tag)

file_path = 'C:\\data2.json'
with open(file_path, 'w') as dataFile:
    json.dump(MyEquipList, dataFile, cls = EquipmentEncoder)
print ("data dumped")

with open(file_path, 'r') as dataFile:
    MyEquipList =  json.load(dataFile,object_hook = EquipmentDecoder)
print ("data loaded")

print(MyEquipList[0].tag)

for e in 

MyEquipList
===========

:
    e.volt_amps()
    e.wire_size()
    print (e.tag, e.VA)
```

Comment: *Why* are you using python 2.7? Any change you can upgrade to 3.x?

Comment: I'm working with Revit/pyRevit/IronPython. It's a company-wide integration. I will eventually be linking my objects to elements in the BIM model. Would upgrading make this problem any easier?

Comment: Yes, it will definitely be much easier with 3.x, especially 3.6+ if you can manage it. The main benefit there is that you can use `dataclasses` in Python for a neat abstraction around classes, and some 3rd party libraries fully support converting dataclasses to/from JSON, with the included tag field to distinguish the instance from the others, I mean.

Comment: Good to know, but pyRevit won't be updated to 3.x for some time. Are there any other work arounds?

Comment: I guess you could check out a library like `jsons` that helps to serialize any class to JSON, but just a note that it's notoriously slow for both deserialization/serialization. I'd also suggest checking out `pickle` library, as it should be faster and I think more memory efficient.